# Does Firefox have an offline throttling mode/disable network feature?

Tags: firefox

I'm doing some front end work and I need to test how the program reacts when it loses a network connection. Firefox has a "Work offline" setting but that drops the connection for every tab -- I only want to disable the network connection for a single tab. Chrome has this with an "Offline" checkbox in the Network tab of the devtools that makes this really convenient.

This is what this feature looks like in Chrome:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox supports this natively since v120. Source: https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/please-add-offline-to-network-throttling-options/idc-p/45653/highlight/true#M26404.

[image]

Comment: Just needed this 6 hours after you answered, thanks, this should be the accepted answer. Looks like the request payload is not available though? Testing it right now while commenting

Comment: Looks like this… Since it's a rather recent feature of Firefox (offline throttling), let's expect it to be polished in some time.

Answer (score 30):

The best solution I've found is to use "Request Blocking". Add `*` to match all requests. It also blocks local requests.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if you are testing a site with a service worker and offline capabilities. When genuinely offline, the browser can still route requests through the service worker, but this solution blocks those requests as well. Using File > Work Offline, as per my answer below, is probably best in this situation.

Comment: This  solution also appears to make the request hang indefinitely rather than fail due to lack of connection.

Comment: Note that requests already initiated doesn't appear to be blocked. Only subsequent requests are blocked,

Answer (score 23):

<strike>As of at most v97, work offline can be found by clicking File > Work Offline in the top left of the window. If you do not have the File menu, try pressing `alt` to make it appear.</strike>

As commentators note, this apparently allows requests to localhost, and will set *all* of your tabs to offline mode.

Greg has a much better answer

Comment: Your bug is marked as duplicate. Vote for this one: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1310986, and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1156659,

Comment: I think this is not what the OP was asking for; this is same as the File -> Work Offline option (it enforces offline mode for *all* tabs, not just a *single* one)

Comment: This is not correct, not only does it set all tabs to offline as @JanakaBandara pointed out, but it also it permits requests to `localhost` so it can't be used in development.

Comment: @RhysvanderWaerden I'm not sure how I missed that in the answer, will update.

Answer (score 5):

Yes we do have the option in firefox

version: 65.01

1. Click on the setting button(hamburger)

[image: step one]

2. Then click the web developer option

[image: step 2]

3. Then click on the work offline option
   [image]

Comment: Still allows localhost to work while other sites are offline (Firefox Dev edition v71)

Answer (score 1):

For at least Firefox v92 (and probably previous ones) offline mode can be found by pressing `ALT` to bring up the File/Edit/View etc menus, then `File > Work Offline`.